# Encode a ImageMagick image with Base64

Tags: perl, imagemagick, base64

I'm creating a thumbnail using Perl's Image::Magick, but I want to send it back to the client inside a JSON object Base64-encoded to be displayed. How could I get the Base64 string without having to save the file to disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you treat a scalar as a filehandle?

http://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Scalar

```
my $image_data;
my $fh = IO::Scalar->new(\$image_data);
$thumbnail->Write(file=> $fh, filename=>'thumbnail.jpg');

## Then as in the previous answer...
my $json = JSON->new->utf8;

my $client_data = {
    thumbnail  => encode_base64( $image_data ),
    other_crap => 'poo',
};

my $encoded_client_data =  $json->encode( $client_data );
```

Edited (c/f [How can I use IO::Scalar with Image::Magick::Read()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899505/how-can-i-use-ioscalar-with-imagemagickread))

How about this:

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php#blobs

> Working with Blobs
>
> A blob contains data that directly represent a particular image format
>   in memory instead of on disk. PerlMagick supports blobs in any of
>   these image formats and provides methods to convert a blob to or from
>   a particular image format.
>
> ...
>
> ImageToBlob() returns the image data in their respective formats.
>   You can then print it, save it to an ODBC database, write it to a
>   file, or pipe it to a display program:

```
 @blobs = $image->ImageToBlob();
  open(DISPLAY,"| display -") || die;
  binmode DISPLAY;
  print DISPLAY $blobs[0];
  close DISPLAY;
```

so you'd want something like:

```
my ($image_data) = ($image->ImageToBlob())[0];
my $json = JSON->new->utf8;

my $client_data = {
    thumbnail  => encode_base64( $image_data ),
    other_crap => 'poo',
};

my $encoded_client_data =  $json->encode( $client_data );
```

Comment: No need for IO::Scalar, just use `open`.

Comment: Your method and @daotoad method didn't work, I tried every possible combination of `$thumbnail->Write` and none of them wrote to `$image_data`, but when you omit `filename` (so it doesn't write to the file) it prints everything to `STDOUT`.

Comment: For some reason I forgot about that shorthand and was looking at the IO::* modules.

Comment: Blobs look like the requisite magick, ++.  Somehow I missed this when I skimmed the docs.  Let's hope they work for @NathanCampos.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Looks like the stuff mentioned here didn't work with Image::Magick.

Further, it looks like Oesor found the right stuff with `ImageToBlob()`.

---

Assuming you have the binary data in a scalar, use MIME::Base64 to encode the binary.  Then use JSON or JSON::XS to create the JSON structure.

MIME::Base64 is a core module.  You should have it already.
JSON and friends are hella useful, you should install one of them already.

```
use MIME::Base64 qw< encode_base64 >;
use JSON;

my $image_data = 'blah';

my $json = JSON->new->utf8;

my $client_data = {
    thumbnail  => encode_base64( $image_data ),
    other_crap => 'poo',
};

my $encoded_client_data =  $json->encode( $client_data );
```

---

**Update:**

I don't see any method exposed for direct access, but you may be able to get away with passing in handle opened on a scalar ref to the `Write()` method.

```
my $image_data;
open my $fh, '>', \$image_data;

$im->Write($fh);

# $image_data now should have the raw binary data.
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was a bit confusing, but I know how to encode something to Base64, what I want to know is how to get the binary data from ImageMagick without saving the image to disk before.

Answer (score 0):

The missing piece I found that put all this together for me was the "magick" parameter when the image is created:

```
use MIME::Base64 qw< encode_base64 >;
use Image::Magick;

$image = Image::Magick->new(size=>'100x100',magick=>'png');
$image->ReadImage('canvas:white');
$text = "12345";
$image->Annotate(font=>'kai.ttf', pointsize=>16, fill=>'green', text=>$text, x=>3.0, y=>17.0);

@blobs = $image->ImageToBlob();
print encode_base64($blobs[0]);
```

Without the "magick->'png'" parameter I didn't get any output (which makes sense, since I never told it how I wanted it formatted).  I was able to add this to a web page using:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAU4AAAATEAIAAAAgxq/gAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAB...
```